# @ManyToOne relations missing from JSON result

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have just started using Spring boot and I am using the default repository api to retrieve db data as json.
I have added a `@ManyToOne` relation to my Song and Artist Entity.

But now i am not getting the Artist object in my json response from the server and its not really clear to me, how I can include it without missing out on the pagination functions from the PagingAndSorting repository.

I am using the spring-data-rest-jpa.

My response now looks like:

```
 "_embedded": {
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "SongTitle",
        "genre": "Rap",
        "length": 500,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs/1"
          },
          "song": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs/1"
          },
          "artist": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs/1/artist"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?page=0&size=1"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?size=1"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?page=1&size=1"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?page=19&size=1"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/songs"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 1,
    "totalElements": 20,
    "totalPages": 20,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

But I want it rather to be like this:

```
"_embedded": {
    "songs": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "SongTitle",
        "genre": "Rap",
        "length": 500,
        "artist": {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Artistname"
        }
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs/1"
          },
          "song": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs/1"
          },
          "artist": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs/1/artist"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?page=0&size=1"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?size=1"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?page=1&size=1"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songs?page=19&size=1"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/songs"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 1,
    "totalElements": 20,
    "totalPages": 20,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

Song.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "song")
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = "The song has to have a title")
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = "The song has to have a genre")
    private String genre;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 1, message = "The song has to have a song length in seconds")
    private int length;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "artist_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Artist artist;

   /* @Version
    private long version;*/

    public Song() {
    }

    public Song(String title, Artist artist, String genre, int length) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void setArtist(Artist artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public Artist getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

  
}
```

Artist.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "artist")
public class Artist {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = "The artist has to have a name")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "artist")
    private List<Song> songs;

    public Artist() {
    }

    public Artist(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

For the sake of testing I wrote a method in my SongController:

```java
@GetMapping
    List<Song> getSongs() {
        return songRepository.findAll();
    }
```

The result includes the Artist object, but won't have any pagination to it. How could I include it?

Json Result:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "SongTitle",
    "genre": "Rap",
    "length": 500,
    "artist": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "ArtistName"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: spring data rest works per default with HATEOAS which returns _just_ the links to the child objects. Therefore your first quest you would need to implement the HATEOS representation by your self.

The second quest: You just return a List of Objects. So why should there be the pagination details?

Comment: I was aware of the links but I didn't want to use them to make additional requests but okay. 
I know that I am returning just a list, that's why I was asking, how I could include Pagination. After all I have solved it, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all your useful suggestions I have found an answer:
I have changed the return type of my Method in my controller to Page and made use of the PageRequest Class which looks like this:

```
@GetMapping
    public Page<Song> getSongs(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "5") int size) {
        PageRequest pr = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        return songRepository.findAll(pr);
    }
```

Also used some defaultvalues to avoid some exceptions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use either @JsonIdentityInfo or @JsonIgnore and remove @JsonBackReference. Here is the example with @JsonIgnore

```
public class Artist {
    public Long id;
    public String name;

    public List<Song> songs;
}

public class Song {
    public Long id;
    public String title;
    public String genre;
    public int length;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Artist artist;
}
```

@JsonManagedReference or @JsonBackReference won't help in this case (read more on https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion):

> (...) we can use the @JsonIgnore annotation to simply ignore one of the sides of the relationship, thus breaking the chain. *[my addition: the chain of recurrent calls]*

Here is the example with @JsonIdentityInfo:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Artist { ... }

@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Song { ... }
```

Comment: hey, I have updated my question. I cant use '@JsonIgnore' on my Artist property in my Song class if I want to display it in my result. I tried your solution with @JsonIdentityInfo but my result remains the same

Comment: Oh, I see. When using the *@JsonIdentityInfo*, did you remove the *@JsonBackReference* and *@JsonIgnore*?

Comment: I tried it again with removing the JsonIgnore and the other way around but it still is remains the same. Is it possible to get the Artist Object in the result of a song object?